# Not permitted when the subquery has expression more than 1 value! in SQL Server 2008

Tags: merge, sql-server-2008-r2, diff

First of all sorry for my english,

I'm trying to insert a record into a table ... the record is the difference between the project table and temp table ...

The code I came into is

```
insert into pro_updatelog 
   select *, @user_n, GETDATE() 
   from pro 
   where cod = (select cod 
                from (SELECT * FROM pro 
                      EXCEPT 
                      SELECT * FROM temp 
                      UNION ALL 
                      SELECT * FROM temp 
                      EXCEPT 
                      SELECT * FROM pro) as T1);
```

then merge the temp table and original table ...

Not sure what should I do ...

All I want is that if there is any differences between the original table and temp table get recorded the original values into pro_updatelog table ... it would be best if only updated value will be recorded in table but it doesn't matter if a full row will be recorded but I want the original values before the update recorded!

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded that by using merge ... how ever it will take much longer to complete the stored procedure but it will do as I want ->

```
insert into pro_updatelog
    select * , @user_n, GETDATE() from
        (SELECT * FROM pro
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * FROM temp
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM temp
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * FROM pro) as T1;
merge pro_updatelog as tar
    using pro as sor
    on (tar.cod = sor.cod)
    when matched then
        update set
            tar.cod = sor.cod ,
            tar.name_pr = sor.name_pr ,
            tar.name_pe = sor.name_pe ,
            tar.en = sor.en ,
            tar.ending = sor.ending ,
            tar.b = sor.b ,
            tar.date_p = sor.date_p ,
            tar.nek = sor.nek ,
            tar.date_kh = sor.date_kh ,
            tar.mp = sor.mp ,
            tar.mt = sor.mt ,
            tar.no_p = sor.no_p ,
            tar.mas = sor.mas ,
            tar.mablag = sor.mablag ,
            tar.np = sor.np ,
            tar.nf = sor.nf ,
            tar.nn = sor.nn ,
            tar.hpp1 = sor.hpp1 ,
            tar.hpp2 = sor.hpp2 ,
            tar.hpp3 = sor.hpp3 ,
            tar.hpp4 = sor.hpp4 ,
            tar.hpp5 = sor.hpp5 ,
            tar.hpp6 = sor.hpp6 ,
            tar.hpp7 = sor.hpp7 ,
            tar.hpp8 = sor.hpp8 ,
            tar.hpf1 = sor.hpf1 ,
            tar.hpf2 = sor.hpf2 ,
            tar.hpf3 = sor.hpf3 ,
            tar.hpf4 = sor.hpf4 ,
            tar.hpf5 = sor.hpf5 ,
            tar.hpf6 = sor.hpf6 ,
            tar.hpf7 = sor.hpf7 ,
            tar.hpf8 = sor.hpf8 ,
            tar.mola = sor.mola ,
            tar.name1 = sor.name1 ,
            tar.name2 = sor.name2 ,
            tar.name3 = sor.name3 ,
            tar.name4 = sor.name4 ,
            tar.name5 = sor.name5 ,
            tar.name6 = sor.name6 ,
            tar.mab_t = sor.mab_t ,
            tar.zarib1 = sor.zarib1 ,
            tar.zarib2 = sor.zarib2 ,
            tar.zarib3 = sor.zarib3 ,
            tar.zarib4 = sor.zarib4 ,
            tar.datet1 = sor.datet1 ,
            tar.datet2 = sor.datet2 ,
            tar.grup = sor.grup ,
            tar.mablag1 = sor.mablag1 ,
            tar.cod_g = sor.cod_g ,
            tar.cod_m = sor.cod_m ,
            tar.user_n = @user_n ,
            tar.[date]=getdate();
```